# Overriding layoutAttributesForElementsInRect in UICollectionViewFlowLayout issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I want to create a custom `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` to change the way the headers and cells are displayed on the collection view.
I subclassed `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and overridden the `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect` method where I create my custom positioned `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes` objects.
The thing is that I am not using `[super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect]` to generate the `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes` and because of that my screen is blank.
If I use the `[super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect]` method to get the `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes`, the collection view is displayed but in the default way.

I am creating my `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes` using this code:

```
UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *cell = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes
                    layoutAttributesForCellWithIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:item inSection:section]];
[cell setAlpha:self.cellOpacity];
[cell setHidden:NO];
[cell setSize:self.itemSize];
[cell setZIndex:self.cellZIndex];
[cell setFrame:CGRectMake ((self.itemSize.width * item) + self.cellPadding,
                    (section * self.itemSize.height) + self.cellPadding,
                    self.itemSize.width,
                    self.itemSize.height)];

[itemsLayoutAttributes addObject:cell];
```

Is something wrong with the fact that I am creating the `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes` manually and not using the ones created by the super method?
What do you think I am doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: check a similar answer that is all about manipulating UICollectionViewFlowLayout: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19712201/ios-uicollectionview-default-flow-fill-rows-from-right-to-left/19923873#19923873 
you can +1 if it helps :)

Comment: you can also try this one:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19474667/uicollectionview-cell-starting-margin

these are all working examples :)

Comment: Thank you very much Raz but I found the issue, you can read it below and it is embarrassing.. I know..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it seems that the only thing I was doing wrong was that I wasn't careful enough to see that the opacity was set to **0** :( .

It seems that my layout now looks alright and indeed one can override `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect` method to create and not only edit the `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes` of that flow layout.